# Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Program Files\Git\opt: Access is denied

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a docker container and it's producing me an error of Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Program Files\Git\opt: Access is denied. I cannot find a documentation/answer relating to this.

This is how I run container: docker run --name jenkins -i -d -p 8787:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:rw local_jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
docker run --name jenkins -i -d -p 8787:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v //opt/docker/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:rw local_jenkins

Comment: This worked for my purpose but.. how?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to add the User's group to the .docker folder and grant full access. Just the new local account access wasn't enough. Just try below

```
net localgroup docker-users "your-user-id" /ADD
```